# Have I calculated the correct EV of Fixed Points

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, permutations

Say we select a permutation $\sigma: [n] \to [n]$ from the permutation of all numbers $\{1,...,n\}$.

$Q1$ Model the corresponding probability space.

Next, define $X$ as an RV for the number of fixed points of $\sigma$.

$Q2$ Determine $\mathbb E[X]$.

**My ideas**:

$Q1$ Define $\Omega:=\{\sigma: [n] \to [n]:\sigma\in\mathcal{S}_{n}\}$ and $\mathcal{F}=2^{\Omega}$ as a result of discreteness, furthermore:

$P(\{\sigma\})=\frac{1}{n!}$

$Q2$ $E[X]=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{1}{n!}\times (n-i)$

I am not sure on $Q2$ though

Comment: U can define $ X_i $ as RV " whether  "i" is a fixed point ", so P($X_i = 1$) = $\frac{1}{n}$ and I would use the linearity of Expected value, cause $X = X_1 + ... + X_n$

Comment: @DominikKutek In that case  I'd get $\mathbb E[X]=1$, correct? Also is my calculation that $P(\{\sigma\})=\frac{1}{n!}$, correct?

Comment: $\mathbb E[X]=1$ and $P(\{\sigma\})=\frac1{n!}$ are both correct results.

Comment: @drhab, perhaps you could explain why my method that does not separate my random variable $X$ into separate $X_{i}$s is incorrect?

Comment: To calculate Expected Value without using linearity, u have to calculate probability that exactly k points are fixed ( name it $p_k$ ). Then $ E[X] = \sum_{k=0}^n kp_k $
If u explain why u thought about $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n-k}{n!}$ then I'll try to say why is that incorrect

Comment: As @DominikKutek remarks: first you should explain how you arrived at the formula for $\mathbb E[X]$. After that it can be explained why it is wrong. Btw, you could try it out on small numbers like $n=2,3$ and try to find the mistake there yourself.